# Longitudinal data format in WinBUGS or OpenBUGS, different number of items per time point

Tags: dataset, ordinal-data, item-response-theory, bugs

I am working with longitudinal data, where there are a different number of "items" per time point. I am working with the `MCMCdynamicIRT1d` function in `MCMCpack` in R to estimate a dynamic IRT model with binary items. However, now I am interested in modeling ordinal items within the same model.

I found an example of a dynamic IRT model with ordinal data in BUGS and the code is based on a CSV data file looks like this:

```
CTRY            YEAR    Item1 Item2 Item3 Item4
Afghanistan     1981        0     1     0     0
Afghanistan     1982        2     0     1     2
....
Albania         1981        0     2     0     0
Albania         1982        1     0     0     1
....
```

The issue is that my data have a different number of "items" per timepoint. I am working with US Supreme Court cases, and the Court sees a different number of cases per year. So my data might look something like this:

```
Justice1 Justice2   year  time
       0        0   1960     1
       1        0   1960     1
       0        1   1960     1
       0        0   1961     2
       0        0   1961     2
       0        0   1961     2
       0        0   1961     2
       0        0   1962     3
       0        0   1962     3
```

Any thoughts on how I can accommodate my data structure with a different number of "items" per time point?

I appreciate any advice you can offer!!!

===== BUGS code I am trying to work with ====

```
model{
for(i in 1:n){# n is the number of obs
for(item in 1:4){
logit(Z[i, item, 1]) <- alpha[item, 1] - beta[item]*x[i]
logit(Z[i, item, 2]) <- alpha[item, 2] - beta[item]*x[i]
Pi[i, item, 1] <- Z[i, item, 1]
Pi[i, item, 2] <- Z[i, item, 2] - Z[i, item, 1]
Pi[i, item, 3] <- 1 - Z[i, item, 2]
y[i, item] ~ dcat(Pi[i, item, 1:3])
}

x[i] <- mu[country[i], year[i]]

}

sigma ~ dunif(0,1)
kappa <- pow(sigma, -1)

for(c in 1:n.country){
mu[c, 1] ~ dnorm(0, 1)

for(t in 2:n.year){ #n.year is number of years
mu[c, t] ~ dnorm(mu[c, t-1], kappa)

}
}

for(j in 1:4){
beta[j] ~ dgamma(4, 3)
alpha0[j, 1] ~ dnorm(0, .25)
alpha0[j, 2] ~ dnorm(0, .25)
alpha[j, 1:2] <- sort(alpha0[j, 1:2])
}
}
```

Comment: BUGS can read data in almost the same format as you present it, see for example the data in the Jama.odc example on the WinBUGS website. http://www.mrc-bsu.cam.ac.uk/software/bugs/the-bugs-project-new-winbugs-examples/